# How to set ActiveWindow.View for the non activesheet

Tags: excel, vba

According to [this article](https://a4accounting.com.au/excel-vba-to-clear-manual-page-breaks/) it states that if you are removing existing page breaks you may get an error if the view for the sheet is set to page break preview. As a solution they say to change the view to normal and then remove the page break.

I was initially trying the following sequence which does not work because I am refering to worksheet instead of activewindow:

```
    ViewState = Worksheets(2).View
    Worksheets(2).View = xlNormalView
    Worksheets(2).Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
    Worksheets(2).View = ViewState
```

Now I could alternate my code to something along the lines of:

```
    Set InitialWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    Worksheets(2).Activate
    ViewState = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    Worksheets(2).Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewState
    InitialWorksheet.Activate
```

**I was wondering if there is a way to change the view state of a non-activesheet without having to activate it first?**

Are Windows index the same way worksheets are index?  is Window(2).view valid?

Comment: From my understanding "View" is not a Worksheet object so you can't use it. The 'ActiveWindow` property represents the active window, so to use the `View` property, the worksheet must be activated. Also, `xlPageBreakNone` will only delete manually set page breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if the workbook is open, changing the `View` setting of a sheet other than the active sheet is not possible.

`xlNormalView` is part of the [XlWindowView type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlwindowview) and as can be read on its MSDN page, it's for specifying the view showing in the **window** (and not the worksheet). Hence, you can only change this property on a window object and the sheet affected will be the one active.

Alternative properties inside the `Window` object aren't helping us either. For instance, if you type

```
Dim wsv As WorksheetView
wsv = ActiveWindow.SheetViews.Item("Sheet1")
```

and then type `wsv.` to look at the available properties in the Intellisense dropdown, you'll only see the following

[image]

which doesn't include anything that would do the equivalent of the `View` property for a single worksheet.

### A potential workaround if the workbook is closed

Knowing that the `View` setting is different from one worksheet to another, Excel has to store the information somewhere. That somewhere is the XML file that is included inside the Excel file (that can be accessed by changing the extension to .zip).

For example, if a worksheet (with code name Sheet1) was saved in Page Break Preview mode, the XML file for that worksheet would include the following:

```
<sheetPr codeName="Sheet1"/><dimension ref="A1"/>
</sheetViews><sheetView tabSelected="1" view="pageBreakPreview" workbookViewId="0"/>
```

So, if you have a lot of sheets to go through and you want to increase the speed of your code by not having to activate each worksheet one at a time, you could code something that would close the workbook, unzip it, edit the XML to change the view options for all sheets and then re-zip it before reopening it.

However, if your code is running on a small number of sheets, this is probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: small number in this case.  What is killing my run time is setting the initial pagesetup properties.  Second run through is lightning fast by comparison since the setting were set on the first pass.  But that is a completely different question for another day

Comment: In this case, you might want to set [PrintCommunication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.printcommunication) to `False` at the start of your code and enable it back at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Set InitialWorksheet = ActiveSheet
Worksheets(2).Activate
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
InitialWorksheet.Activate
```

Hope it helps